# How to get this project up and running on an Android?

Tags: android

[This project](https://github.com/getSizeOf) at a hackathon was just simply ingenious. And as a curious noob, I want to check it out. They don't have it on PlayStore, nor did they have an APK, but I want to see how it works. So how would I run this on Android?

It's also important to note that this is *not a typical Android project*. This doesn't work with just importing it to android studio. Trust me, I've tried it like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to terminal/cmd git it by the URL:

   `git clone https://github.com/getSizeOf/sizeOf-Droid.git`
2. Open Android Studio click on import project, click import project
   [image]
3. Click on build.gradle on the project level
   [image]
4. Project opened, get coding!!!
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the project with 'project' being the root folder. I just opened it in Android Studio 1.2.2 (latest) and it works fine.

Sometimes, when you open an existing project, you have to expand to show the project structure by clicking on "1. Project" and then select "Project" from the drop-down menu (person preference).

[image: Project structure]

To run on a device, select "Run" from the toolbar then click 'Run app' from the drop down menu.